# Ruby on Rails - Which direction should I go in for building an INTERACTIVE INTERFACE?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, interface

So I have my first Ruby on Rails application ready for an interface. I want to add some type of Javascript to improve the user experience and some design to make the interface look crisp. Staying within the HTML5, CSS3, and Javascript arena which direction should I go in for building this interface? Keep in mind I'm a beginner.

There are three main things this interface has:
1. Displays value (0-100) from a controller @variable as a gauge.
2. Lists contents of an array in order. (see code below)
3. Execute ruby's button_to code. (see code below)

```
<div id="page-wrap">
<% @finalcarssneeded.each do|x| %>
<div><%= button_to "add #{x}", send(:"#{x}a_cars_path", id: @user.id),  class: "btn       btn-large btn-primary" %></div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Any tips you can provide on tutorials, Javascript frameworks, or any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: I've used jQuery/Twitter Bootstrap/erb with success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of 2 very popular ways to get started.

1. Have a look at [Twitter Bootsrap](http://railscasts.com/episodes/328-twitter-bootstrap-basics), and here's a [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/328-twitter-bootstrap-basics) on how to use it. That will get you going fairly quick.
2. [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) that will give you a head start on hooking up javascript to Rails. And IIRC Rails 3 ships with JQuery, so you're already using it.